# Integration Proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is defined on $I = [0,10]$ as follows: $f(x) = N$ if $N-1 \leq x < N$ and that $P = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \in \prod(I)$.

- Find $S[f,P]$ and $s[f,P]$
- I'm not sure how to approach these problems.
- I know that I have to define: 
  $$s[f:P_n] = \sum_{k=1}^{n} m_k |I_k|$$
  $$S[f:P_n] = \sum_{k=1}^{n} M_k |I_k|$$
- But I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm supposed to define $m_k$,$M_k$, and $|I_k|$ along with actually calculating the upper and lower sums. Would $|I_k| = n$ since the partition is uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper and lower sums defined with respect to a partition $(a =x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1},x_n = b)$ of the interval $[a,b]$ are given by

$$S(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)(x_j - x_{j-1}), \\s(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)(x_j - x_{j-1}). $$

In this case, $a = 0$, $b = 10$, $n = 10$, and $x_j = 0 + (10-0)(j/n) = j$ for $j = 1,2 , \ldots, 10$.

Hence,

$$S(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^{10} \sup_{x \in [j-1,j]}f(x), \\s(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^{10} \inf_{x \in [j-1,j]}f(x). $$

Given your definition of $f$ we have

$$\inf_{x \in [j-1,j]}f(x) = j, $$

and for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant 9$

$$sup_{x \in [j-1,j]}f(x) = j+1.$$

It appears that $f(10) = 11$. Even if you left $f(10)$ undefined, we could assign an arbitrary value and

$$\sup_{x \in [9,10]}f(x) = \max(10,f(10)).$$

Thus,

$$S(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^{9}(j+1) + \max(10,f(10)), \\s(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^{10} j. $$